# Permission denied(publickey) Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, ssh, digital-ocean

I am trying to push my site to my server on digital ocean but I keep getting this error.

```
local-machine@my-server-address: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have already set up the ssh key and used it on my server. I am able to ssh into the site but when I try to use the git remote then access is denied. I have double checked my repositories.

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v` what is the exact push command you typed.

Comment: production ssh://server-address/var/repo/site.git (fetch)
    production ssh://server-address/var/repo/site.git (push)

Comment: Do you use a specific user name to log in via SSH? If so, that user name needs to be part of the URL as well, i.e. it should be `ssh://user@server-address/var/repo/site.git`. Also if you use a specific SSH key (using `ssh -i ...` for login) it would be simpler to make an SSH config entry for the host and reference that entry in the URL.

Comment: Just seen this. You are right that was the issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that is very obvious is the fact that you're using **SSH Key**, and what happens is that digital ocean isn't able to authenticate you. "So, either you aren't setup with an SSH key, because you haven't set one up on your machine, or your key isn't associated with your digital ocean account.

Another option you might want to try is pushing it using the **HTTPS URL** instead of the SSH URL to avoid having to deal with SSH keys.

You might want read further on git [Error: Permission denied (publickey)](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey)

Comment: I have set up a key on my machine as well as associating it to the the server in question. I am able to ssh into the server using the same key.

Comment: Have you ensured that you have keys on both sides of the servers, i.e both production and local? Maybe you might want to try to ssh `admin@PRODUCTION_IP_ADDRESS` with your terminal from your development server. You might possibly have that error because you couldn't connect, and you didn't  only had the Production SSH key on the development server and not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance I found what was missing. The problem was in the git remote I was using to push the app.

Comment: @JohnmarkWachira glad to hear that your problem has been solved. Maybe you could then accept the answer then for others to get to know the solution for next time.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the help. I figured out the issue. I had added a remote without specifying the user.

```
git remote add production ssh://my-server-address/var/repo/site.git
```

Instead of

```
git remote add production ssh://root@my-server-address/var/repo/site.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of `git remote -v` . Make Sure you are pointed at the correct repo.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is for Github user. According the url: https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

add one line into the `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
  User git     <-------this line.
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```